# javascript: How to swap players turns in a Game?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, tic-tac-toe

I'm working on two player game I need to swap the players after every move.

Currently I have this javascript:

```
var play = function(player, opp) {
    var index;
    player.play(function(move) {
        index = move;
        board.board[index][1] = player.mark;
        if (board.weHaveWinner()==undefined||!board.isFull()) {
            play(opp,player);
        }
    });
}
```

The issue that the player that moved wont be drawn until the opponent calculates his move.

How can I make this asynchronous?

Comment: What does `player.play`? You seem to pass a callback to that function, is it async? Also, what triggers a `play` call?

Comment: Also, when does the drawing code executes?

Answer (score 1):

The browser hangs when you run your recursive function.  The javascript function `setTimeout(...)` will pass control back to the browser briefly for rendering your board, then after a time it will resume recursively calling `play(...)`:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout

So something like this:

```
window.setInterval(play(opp,player),100);
```

So the browser renders board with the mark, then resumes calling the next layer deep of method play after 100 milliseconds.